# Understanding the Reference Handler thread

Tags: java, reference, thread-dump

I am continuing my path to deep understanding of Java Thread. Unfortunately my Java Certification didn't cover that part, so the only way of learning is to post a series of dumb questions. With so many years of Java Development, I am sometimes wondering how much I still have to learn :-)

In particular my attention is now with the reference handler thread.

```
"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02da3400 nid=0xb98 in Object.wait() [0x0302f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x1aac0320> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x1aac0320> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
```

Now some questions are following, for some of them I know the answer, but I am not posting it, because I would like to hear someone else opinions:

1. What is the Reference Handler thread supposed to do ?
2. A thread dump should be considered bottom up, why does the stack trace start with locked, shouldn't the lock statement appears at least after the thread has run ?
3. What does "Native Method" means ?
4. Why "Unknown Source", in which case the thread dump cannot recall the source code ?
5. Lastly the waiting on and locked has the same , why ?

as usual, I kindly ask to answer all the questions, so that I can mark answered.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. I *suspect* it handles running finalizers for the JVM. It's an implementation detail and as such not specified in the JVM spec.
2. This only means that the `java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock` was locked in the method mentioned in the line *preceding* it (i.e in `ReferenceHandler.run()`.
3. "Native Method" simply means that the method is implemented in native (i.e. non-Java) code (think JNI).
4. Unknown Source only means that the `.class` file doesn't contain any source code location information (at least for this specific point). This can happen *either* when the method is a synthetic one (doesn't look like it here), or the class was compiled without debug information.
5. When a thread *waits* on some object, then it *must* have locked that object at some point down the call trace, so you *can't* really have a `waiting on` without a corresponding `locked`.

Comment: Uhm...regarding point 5, it makes sense, can we say that when a 'waiting on' statement appear, then later in the stack trace a 'lock' with the same address ALWAYS appear ?

Comment: well, if you could explain more about question 1, I could mark the whole as solved :-)

Answer (score 4):

1) The Finalizer Thread calls finalizer methods.
The Reference Thread has a similar purpose.

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/lang/java/lang/ref/Reference.java.htm

The OpenJDK source states its is a

> High-priority thread to enqueue pending References

The GC creates a simple linked list of references which need to be processed and this thread quickly adds them to a proper queue.  The reason this is done in two phases is that the GC does nothing but find the References, this thread calls code which handles those references e.g. Call Cleaners, and notifies ReferenceQueue listeners.

2) A lock is acquired for a synchronized method before it is entered.

3-5) covered by Joachim ;)

Comment: Great. Could you explain what is meant by pending references?

Comment: @JavaTechnical These are references to object which need finalize() called on them before they are cleaned up on the next GC.

Comment: Thanks. So that means, does finalize() check whether they need to be de-allocated or not? This is done by checking if there are any reference(s) pointing to that object? Am i right?

Comment: A object can be cleaned up when there is no strong references to it.  `finalize()` is called if it is overridden, even if it is overridden with an empty method.

Comment: I have a question, if a 1GB file that is mapped to directbytebuffer, when I call clean explictly, which will be "blocking the reference-handler thread"(according to http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Cleaner.html), will this have performace impact(or blocking  ) that when another thread are creating objects bdefore clean is done?

Comment: @Jaskey If you explicitly clean the resource, it doesn't need to be cleaned in a background thread which is what it would block. Unless you have a 32-bit JVM, virtual memory isn't likely to be a limited resources so it's unlikely to impact you.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, too deep for me. I can only answer one or two of your questions.

"Native Method" simply means the implementation of that method is in some native (i.e. C or C++) library. Once the call stack has "gone native", the JVM can no longer monitor it. No way for it to provide additional stack information.

"Unknown Source" likely means the code was compiled with optimization turned on and debugging info turned off (`-g` flag?). This eliminates the file/line information from the .class file.

Comment: Good answer for 3 and 4, unfortunately I need all of them to mark as answered.